# variableReplace showing a error

Tags: java, docx, docx4j

I have went onto the GitHub repository for the docx4j files and downloaded VariableReplace.  When i copied this file into netbeans, I got an error on line 86 (Cannont find symbol).

Here is the code:

```
/*
 *  Copyright 2007-2008, Plutext Pty Ltd.
 *   
 *  This file is part of docx4j.

    docx4j is licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); 
    you may not use this file except in compliance with the License. 

    You may obtain a copy of the License at 

        http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0 

    Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software 
    distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, 
    WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. 
    See the License for the specific language governing permissions and 
    limitations under the License.

 */


import java.util.HashMap;

import org.docx4j.XmlUtils;
import org.docx4j.jaxb.Context;
import org.docx4j.openpackaging.io.SaveToZipFile;
import org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.WordprocessingMLPackage;
import org.docx4j.openpackaging.parts.WordprocessingML.MainDocumentPart;
import org.docx4j.wml.Document;


/**
 * There are at least 3 approaches for replacing variables in 
 * a docx.
 * 
 * 1. as shows in this example
 * 2. using Merge Fields (see org.docx4j.model.fields.merge.MailMerger)
 * 3. binding content controls to an XML Part (via XPath)
 * 
 * Approach 3 is the recommended one when using docx4j. See the 
 * ContentControl* examples, Getting Started, and the subforum.
 * 
 * Approach 1, as shown in this example, works in simple cases
 * only.  It won't work if your KEY is split across separate
 * runs in your docx (which often happens), or if you want 
 * to insert images, or multiple rows in a table.
 * 
 * You're encouraged to investigate binding content controls
 * to an XML part.  There is org.docx4j.model.datastorage.migration.FromVariableReplacement
 * to automatically convert your templates to this better
 * approach.
 * 
 * OK, enough preaching.  If you want to use VariableReplace,
 * your variables should be appear like so: ${key1}, ${key2} 
 * 
 * And if you are having problems with your runs being split,
 * VariablePrepare can clean them up.
 *
 */
public class VariableReplace {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        // Exclude context init from timing
        org.docx4j.wml.ObjectFactory foo = Context.getWmlObjectFactory();

        // Input docx has variables in it: ${colour}, ${icecream}
        String inputfilepath = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/sample-docs/word/unmarshallFromTemplateExample176.docx";

        boolean save = false;
        String outputfilepath = System.getProperty("user.dir")
                + "/OUT_VariableReplace.docx";

        WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage = WordprocessingMLPackage
                .load(new java.io.File(inputfilepath));
        MainDocumentPart documentPart = wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart();

        HashMap<String, String> mappings = new HashMap<String, String>();
        mappings.put("colour", "green");
        mappings.put("icecream", "chocolate");

        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

        // Approach 1 (from 3.0.0; faster if you haven't yet caused unmarshalling to occur):

            documentPart.variableReplace(mappings);

/*      // Approach 2 (original)

            // unmarshallFromTemplate requires string input
            String xml = XmlUtils.marshaltoString(documentPart.getJaxbElement(), true);
            // Do it...
            Object obj = XmlUtils.unmarshallFromTemplate(xml, mappings);
            // Inject result into docx
            documentPart.setJaxbElement((Document) obj);
*/

        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long total = end - start;
        System.out.println("Time: " + total);

        // Save it
        if (save) {
            SaveToZipFile saver = new SaveToZipFile(wordMLPackage);
            saver.save(outputfilepath);
        } else {
            System.out.println(XmlUtils.marshaltoString(documentPart.getJaxbElement(), true,
                    true));
        }
    }

}
```

Does anyone know why I am getting this error?

Here are a few pictures:

[image: Error 1 Overview]

[image: Error 1 Details]

Thanks Hrach

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

I do not get any immediate errors, but when I run the code below, i get these errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Logger
    at org.docx4j.openpackaging.Base.<clinit>(Base.java:42)
    at VariableReplace.main(VariableReplace.java:61)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.log4j.Logger
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    ... 2 more
Java Result: 1
```

I just figured out the problem :).  I was using the old samples.

Here is the new code:

```
/*
 *  Copyright 2007-2008, Plutext Pty Ltd.
 *   
 *  This file is part of docx4j.

    docx4j is licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); 
    you may not use this file except in compliance with the License. 

    You may obtain a copy of the License at 

        http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0 

    Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software 
    distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, 
    WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. 
    See the License for the specific language governing permissions and 
    limitations under the License.

 */

package org.docx4j.samples;


import java.util.HashMap;

import org.docx4j.XmlUtils;
import org.docx4j.openpackaging.io.SaveToZipFile;
import org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.WordprocessingMLPackage;
import org.docx4j.openpackaging.parts.WordprocessingML.MainDocumentPart;
import org.docx4j.wml.Document;


/**
 * There are at least 3 approaches for replacing variables in 
 * a docx.
 * 
 * 1. as shows in this example
 * 2. using Merge Fields (see org.docx4j.model.fields.merge.MailMerger)
 * 3. binding content controls to an XML Part (via XPath)
 * 
 * Approach 3 is the recommended one when using docx4j. See the 
 * ContentControl* examples, Getting Started, and the subforum.
 * 
 * Approach 1, as shown in this example, works in simple cases
 * only.  It won't work if your KEY is split across separate
 * runs in your docx (which often happens), or if you want 
 * to insert images, or multiple rows in a table.
 * 
 * You're encouraged to investigate binding content controls
 * to an XML part.
 *
 */
public class VariableReplace {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String inputfilepath = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/sample-docs/word/unmarshallFromTemplateExample.docx";

        boolean save = false;
        String outputfilepath = System.getProperty("user.dir")
                + "/OUT_VariableReplace.docx";

        WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage = WordprocessingMLPackage
                .load(new java.io.File(inputfilepath));
        MainDocumentPart documentPart = wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart();

        // unmarshallFromTemplate requires string input
        String xml = XmlUtils.marshaltoString(documentPart.getJaxbElement(), true);

        HashMap<String, String> mappings = new HashMap<String, String>();
        mappings.put("colour", "green");
        mappings.put("icecream", "chocolate");

        // Do it...
        Object obj = XmlUtils.unmarshallFromTemplate(xml, mappings);

        // Inject result into docx
        documentPart.setJaxbElement((Document) obj);

        // Save it
        if (save) {
            SaveToZipFile saver = new SaveToZipFile(wordMLPackage);
            saver.save(outputfilepath);
        } else {
            System.out.println(XmlUtils.marshaltoString(documentPart.getJaxbElement(), true,
                    true));
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Not sure whether you've solved your problem or not, but you need the log4j jar (and docx4j's other dependencies) on your classpath.

Comment: I have the jar file, but I am not sure if it is in my class path, thanks.  I'll try this when i get home.